# What is the git command to list ignored files?

Tags: git

My netbeans IDE shows ignored files on a different color.
I presume, the IDE is knowing this by using some git command.

I wish to know what files on a project folder and subfolders are being ignored.

What command should we use?

Comment: @trojanfoe - as far as I can tell, I didn't understand the answer given on that question, hence, asking it again, expecting to have a more clear answer. That was the case. - For the sake of clarity, I presume this question and Max answer, should be kept on SO.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`git status --ignored` will show all untracked files. It also includes the normal status output. There does not appear to be a status option to only show the ignored files.

Comment: Does not include those entries from global gitignore it seems

Comment: @MichaelHeuberger, it actually does include those entries, at least in my setup, in git version 2.39.0.windows.2